# Como actualizar un JTable al modificar mi arreglo 2d

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, jtable

Estaba intentando actualizar un JTable luego de modificar el arreglo bidimensional que utilizo como fuente, pero no se actualiza. Lo que hice fue crear un DefaultTableModel y añadirlo a mi tabla.

Cuando los datos del arreglo cambien utilizo el método `fireTableDataChanged()` pero no pasa nada con mi tabla.

Lo importante está en el ActionListener del botón "CargaMasiva", este es mi código:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PanelSucursal extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private String [][] tablasucu = new String[50][5];
    private String [] ColumnasTabla = {"Código", "Nombre", "Dirección", "Correo", "Teléfono"};

    DefaultTableModel ModeloTabla = new DefaultTableModel(ModuloAdmin.ArregloBidimensionalSucursales,ColumnasTabla);
    private JTable tabla = new JTable();

    private Sucursal [] ArregloSucursales;
    public Sucursal [] ArregloSucursales2;

    private JButton ExportarPDF = new JButton();
    private JButton Crear= new JButton();
    private JButton CargaMasiva= new JButton();
    private JButton Eliminar = new JButton();
    private JButton Actualizar = new JButton();

    JScrollPane scroll  = new JScrollPane(tabla);

    public PanelSucursal() {
        tabla.setModel(ModeloTabla);
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        add(scroll);
        add(AddBotones());
    }

    public JPanel AddBotones() {
        Crear.addActionListener(this);
        ExportarPDF.addActionListener(this);
        CargaMasiva.addActionListener(this);
        Eliminar.addActionListener(this);
        Actualizar.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.ipadx = 16;
        gbc.ipady = 16;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        Crear.setText("Crear");
        CargaMasiva.setText("Carga masiva");
        Actualizar.setText("Actualizar");
        Eliminar.setText("Eliminar");
        ExportarPDF.setText("Exportar a listado PDF");

        panel.add(Crear, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(CargaMasiva, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        panel.add(Actualizar, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(Eliminar, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        panel.add(ExportarPDF, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == Crear) {

        }

        if (e.getSource() == CargaMasiva) {
            LecturaJSON();
            ModuloAdmin.ArregloBidimensionalSucursales=ArregloBidimensionalSucursales();
        
            for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++) {
                    System.out.print(ModuloAdmin.ArregloBidimensionalSucursales[i][j]);
                }

                System.out.println();
            }

            ModeloTabla.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == Eliminar) {
            System.out.println("Presionó Eliminar");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == ExportarPDF) {
            System.out.println("Presionó PDF");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == Actualizar) {
            System.out.println("Presionó Actualizar");
        }
    }

    private void LecturaJSON() {
        int contador = 0;
        BufferedReader MiBuffer;
        String ContenidoJson = "";
        String linea = "";

        JFileChooser Selector = new JFileChooser();
        int respuesta = Selector.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (respuesta == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                File archivo = new File(Selector.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                FileReader lector = new FileReader(archivo);

                MiBuffer = new BufferedReader(lector);

                while (linea != null) {
                    linea=MiBuffer.readLine();
                    if (linea != null) {
                        ContenidoJson += linea;
                    }

                }
                MiBuffer.close();

                //Obtener objetos del JSON
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                ArregloSucursales = gson.fromJson(ContenidoJson, Sucursal[].class);
                Sucursal tempo [] = new Sucursal[ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales.length+ArregloSucursales.length];
                System.arraycopy(ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales, 0, tempo, 0, ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales.length);
                System.arraycopy(ArregloSucursales, 0, tempo,  ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales.length, ArregloSucursales.length);
                // ArregloSucursales2=tempo;
                ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales=tempo;
               // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El archivo Json tiene algo mal");
            }
        }
    }

    private String [][] ArregloBidimensionalSucursales() {
        String[][] tempo = new String[ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales.length][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < ArregloSucursales.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++) {
                if(j==0) {
                    tempo[i][j]=ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales[i].getCodigo();
                }
                if(j==1) {
                    tempo[i][j]=ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales[i].getNombre();
                }
                if(j==2) {
                    tempo[i][j]=ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales[i].getDireccion();
                }
                if(j==3) {
                    tempo[i][j]=ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales[i].getCorreo();
                }

                if(j==4) {
                    tempo[i][j]=ModuloAdmin.ArregloPrincipalSucursales[i].getTelefono();
                }
            }
        }

        return tempo;
    }

}
```